# Constructor inheritance and direct member initialisation

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, constructor

I am trying to use a combination of the C++ 11 direct data member initialisation and the "using" syntax to inherit the constructors of a base class. Now with gcc 5.4.0 (on Ubuntu 16.04) I observe a strange error, if the data member type has no default constructor. It is probably easiest to understand when looking on the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  Foo(int arg) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(" << arg << ")" << std::endl; }
};

struct Base {
  Base(int arg) { std::cout << "Base::Base(" << arg << ")" << std::endl; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  using Base::Base;
  Foo foo{42};
};

int main() {
  Derived derived{120};
}
```

This code compiles and executes with the expected behaviour with clang. With gcc it does not compile, because the compiler deletes the constructor `Derived::Derived(int)`:

```
ttt.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ttt.cpp:17:22: error: use of deleted function ‘Derived::Derived(int)’
   Derived derived{120};
                      ^
ttt.cpp:12:15: note: ‘Derived::Derived(int)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   using Base::Base;
               ^
ttt.cpp:12:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo()’
ttt.cpp:4:3: note: candidate: Foo::Foo(int)
   Foo(int arg) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(" << arg << ")" << std::endl; }
   ^
ttt.cpp:4:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
ttt.cpp:3:8: note: candidate: constexpr Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
 struct Foo {
        ^
ttt.cpp:3:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
ttt.cpp:3:8: note: candidate: constexpr Foo::Foo(Foo&&)
ttt.cpp:3:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

If I add a default constructor to Foo like this:

```
  Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo()" << std::endl; };
```

also gcc can compile it. The code behaves exactly in the same way, in particular the added default constructor of Foo never gets executed.

So my question is now, is this valid C++ 11? If yes, I probably have found a bug in gcc. Otherwise, shouldn't both gcc and clang give me an error message that this is not valid C++ 11?

Edit after the question was nicely answered by @vlad-from-moscow: This bug seems to be present also in gcc 6.2, so I will file a bug report.

2nd edit: There already is a bug, which I didn't find in the first search: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67054

Comment: I cannot find anything about this on pages like cppreference.com. Both the "using" syntax and the brace initialiser are described there, but it is not mentioned anything about combining both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The gcc does not satisfy the C++ Standard. The inherited constructor of the class Derived should call the Base constructor in its mem-initializer list with the argument specified for the Derived inherited constructor.

There is written in the C++ Standard (12.9 Inheriting constructor)

> 8 An inheriting constructor for a class is implicitly deﬁned when it
>   is odr-used (3.2) to create an object of its class type (1.8). An
>   implicitly-deﬁned inheriting constructor performs the set of
>   initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written
>   inline constructor for that class **with a mem-initializer-list whose
>   only mem-initializer has a mem-initializer-id that names the base
>   class denoted in the nested-name-speciﬁer of the using-declaration and
>   an expression-list as speciﬁed below**, and where the
>   compound-statement in its function body is empty (12.6.2). If that
>   user-written constructor would be ill-formed, the program is
>   ill-formed. Each expression in the expression-list is of the form
>   static_cast(p), where p is the name of the corresponding
>   constructor parameter and T is the declared type of p.

Also according to the section (12.6.2 Initializing bases and members)

> 8 In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member
>   or base class is not designated by a mem-initializer-id (including the
>   case where there is no mem-initializer-list because the constructor
>   has noctor-initializer) and the entity is not a virtual base class of
>   an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer, the entity is initialized as specified in
>   8.5;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: The issue is not so much that `Derived(120)` does not call `Base(120)` and more that it mistakenly assumes the expression-list will be `foo()` (which is invalid) even though an initializer is provided and the actual call will be `foo(42)`. If you remove the `foo` data member, then gcc accepts the code.

Comment: @MatthieuM.  I have appended my answer. However I found that there are contradictions between various editions of the Standard.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're right, there's a bug in gcc

From §12.9 [class.inhctor]:

> A *using-declaration* (7.3.3) that names a constructor implicitly declares a set of *inheriting constructors*. The
>   candidate set of *inherited constructors* from the class `X` named in the *using-declaration* consists of actual
>   constructors and notional constructors that result from the transformation of defaulted parameters as follows:
>
> - all non-template constructors of `X`

So this means that your `Derived` class should definnitely get a constructor from its base that accepts an `int`. Following the normal rules of in-class member initialization, constructing an instance of `Derived` shouldn't be a problem without a default constructor for `Foo` because it's not being used. Hence, there's a bug in gcc:

§13.3.1.3 Initialization by constructor [over.match.ctor]

> When objects of class type are direct-initialized (8.5) [...], overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization, **the candidate
>   functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized**.

So the constructor `Foo::Foo(int)` should have been selected, which it clearly wasn't in gcc.

---

One question I had after reading this was "Does this cause the default constructor for `Derived` to be deleted?" The answer is no.

Conveniently, the standard provides an example below this excerpt (I'm excising what's not needed):

```
struct B1 {
   B1(int);
};

struct D1 : B1 {
   using B1::B1;
};
```

> The set of constructors present in `D1` is [**Emphasis** mine]
>
> - **`D1()`, implicitly-declared default constructor, ill-formed if odr-used**
> - `D1(const D1&)`, implicitly-declared copy constructor, not inherited
> - `D1(D1&&)`, implicitly-declared move constructor, not inherited
> - `D1(int)`, implicitly-declared inheriting constructor

Comment: This has nothing to do with the default constructor of Derived or Base. gcc requires a default constructor of Foo, but it never actually calls it.

Comment: @MartinHierholzer: You said "This code compiles and executes with the expected behaviour with clang. With gcc it does not compile, because the compiler deletes the constructor of Derived:". This is incorrect gcc behavior, and what I'm addressing here. You shouldn't need to do anything more.

Comment: Referring to your edit: This is still not about whether the default constructor of Derived gets deleted or not. I am not interested in the default constructor of Derived, it is never used and gcc never complained about not having it. Instead, gcc deletes the wanted constructor Derived::Derived(int), because the default constructor of Foo does not exist!

Comment: @MartinHierholzer: I've made more edits for clarity. I don't think I can make a stronger argument than this.